# Formatting java class

Tags: string, class, formatting

I have a string which contains Java class as a string.

for e.g.

```
String class = "class MyClass{\n private int myInt;\n}";
```

How can I format this into a well indented 'class string'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a indent for every "{\n" and remove the indent for every "}". Keep a counter of braces that will start at 0. After first "{", braces =1. After "}" it becomes 0.
That way you'll end up with this

```
class MyClass {\n
<indent>private int myInt;\n
}
```

Keep the same indent for all new lines.

Comment: It would be great if there is some utility that include import statements also.